# django session key error for my simple captcha form

Tags: django, session, captcha

I just write a simple captcha for my login form.
I just add a simple session `data.request.session['captcha']`.
This is the login views function:

```
login (request):
 if request.method =='GET':
   form = LoginForm(auto_id=True)
   a = random.randrange(1,10,1)
   b = random.randrange(10,20.1)
   request.session['captcha1']=a
   request.session['captcha2']=b

   return render_to_response('login.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))

 if request.method =='POST':
    form = LoginForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
       captcha= request.POST.get('captcha','')
       result = request.session.get('captcha1') + request.session.get('captcha2')
       if captcha==result:
          data = form.clean()
          user=authenticate(username= data['username'],password = data['password'])
          if user is not None:
              auth_login(request,user)
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
    else:
       form = LoginForm(auto_id=True)   
    return render_to_response('login.html',locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

This is the login form

```
class  LoginForm (forms.Form):    
    username = forms.CharField( 
        label='username')
    password =forms.CharField( 
        label='password',widget = forms.PasswordInput())
    captcha = forms.CharField(label='spam chercker')
```

I get keyerror for captcha1, captcha2, and when I add `print request.session['captcha1']`, it shows `None`. That means, when POST, I do not get the django session data, there is no data captcha1 and captcha2

How can I store the data in django session, and pass it to the POST method, and in other views function?

thanks

Comment: What is this: `request.session.get('captcha1)+request.session.get('captcha2)` ? Are the single quotes proper? Similarly the print statement also has a missing single quote.

Comment: my captcha is simple math question like 2+12=?
so capthcha1 is 2 ,captcha2 = 12,user must input 14

Answer (score 0):

Instead of taking this approach, you might also want to look at existing Django captcha packages:
https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/captcha/

If you're looking for something simple, Django-Simple-Captcha is a great option.